# start timer when user click button, React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a function in which when user click start button timer will start, but it's not working. Can someone tell me why it's not working? please

that's the function I created

````
const [time,setTime] = useState(0)

  const timeout = setInterval(() => {
        if (time !== 60) {
          setTime(prevState => prevState + 1);
        }
      }, 1000);
      console.log(timeout);
      return () => {
        if (time == 60) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
      };```
````

Comment: I don't know React but isn't this problem due to `useState({timer:0})` ?

Comment: `setTimeout` will only execute once at the specified interval. Instead, I think you want `setInterval` which will run repeatedly at the specified time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

> why is my code not working?

Your state `timer` starts out being 0 and will therefore never reach inside the `if` statement.

As Matt U pointed out you most likely want to use `setInterval` since it runs the function you pass at every X milliseconds (1000 in your case) until you stop it.

See the following for more information regarding that:

- setTimeout: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
- setInterval: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

What yesIamFaded answered should do the job in your use case, though it would be better to make use of `updateState`'s argument `prevState` (or whatever you want to call it). `updateState` will receive the previous value and use that to compute a new value.

```
const [state, updateState] = useState({ timer: 60 })

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (state.timer > 0) {
        updateState(prevState => { timer: prevState.timer - 1 });
    }
}, 1000);
```

You can read more about functional updates here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

And lastly, you should clear the timeout and/or interval once you don't need it anymore using either `clearTimeout()` or `clearInterval()`.

See the following for more information here:

- clearTimeout: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp
- clearInterval: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

P.S.

If your `timer` state isn't coupled with any other state I wouldn't put it into an object. Instead I would do the following:

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(60)

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (timer > 0) {
        setTimer(prevTimer => prevTimer - 1 );
    }
}, 1000);
```

That way you won't have an unnecessary object.

Comment: well, it worked worked.But timer stopped after 1 second

Comment: @DarkPrince did you switch setTimeout to use setInterval?

Comment: @DarkPrince you have to use setInterval if you wish for it to keep going each interval. setTimeout will only run once after the given milliseconds.

Comment: yes I did, but it's keep returning 2 numbers 1 and 2, I updated my mode in my question

Comment: Try and use the previous state argument that the `updateState`, or in my example `setTimer` has. If you look at my example I use the `prevState` argument to make sure it's always the previous state value which is being used to make the computation.
Also, as I mentioned in my answer you should clear your interval when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: @DarkPrince Did I answer your question or do you still have problems with this?

Comment: oh sorry for late rply, I was busy in other things. 
I tried your ans right now ,it's working but I unable to stop it even if i click on stop button

Comment: `clearTimeout(timeout);` I'm using this to stop timer. AlsoI updated my code in my question

Comment: Sorry for the even later reply @DarkPrince.

If you use `setInterval` you'll have to use `clearInterval` as `clearTimeout` is for clearing a `setTimeout`.

Also, if you want to have it incrementing as long as it's under 60 seconds I would write `time < 60` instead of `time !== 60`. It's more concise and you can easily tell the intent of the code.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare the Timer State as 60 instead of 0 and

```
const [state,updateState] = useState({timer:60})
```

then call this in updateState: `({timer: timer - 1})`